# .Net analog of GWT?

Tags: .net, gwt

Do you know analog of GWT on .Net? Or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp)
From their website:

> Script# brings productivity to Ajax and JavaScript development. Script# is a free tool that enables developers to author C# source code and subsequently compile it into regular script that works across all modern browsers, and in doing so, leverage the productivity and power of existing .NET tools as well as the Visual Studio IDE. Script# empowers you with a development methodology and approach that brings software engineering, long term maintainability and scalable development approaches for your Ajax applications, components and frameworks.
>   Script# is used extensively by developers within Microsoft building Ajax experiences in Windows Live, Office to name just a couple, as well as by a external developers and companies including Facebook. If you’re building Ajax-based RIA applications, you owe it to yourself to try Script# today and see if it can help improve your own Ajax development!

Answer (score 1):

Best I can recommend are the telerik controls.

The [Ajax Toolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) is not bad either, but not nearly as productive as the teleriks.

You have the option with asp.net webforms to make everything in code behind. Especially with the WPF-Platform.

Have a look here:

http://demos.telerik.com/wpf/

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: @Edward83: No that's maybe the problem. But the free trials are for 60 days. Some controls are for free. But the cheapest license is about 800$. This is no ad by the way. The controls are just astonishing.